# Is it possible to use AWS API without Authentication Token

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, authentication, aws-lambda

I try to use AWS lambda. I don't want to use any authentication - it is a simple test function. I receive

```
{
    "message": "Missing Authentication Token"
}
```

Is it possible to use AWS API without Authentication Token?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should (almost) always use authentication. It's trivially easy to supply credentials. Not requiring authentication opens you up to potentially unbounded costs and increases the likelihood that you will accidentally deploy an unauthenticated service to production.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's possible. You can configure if you want to use Authorization, Request Validator or API key for each resource you created.

Also make sure you invoke the right URL and **path** of your API, because I had the same issue when I tried to trigger an undeclared path.

[image: AWS console]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create it without Authentication. It means it will default execution role. I have a video blog on the same, which creates and run API without any authentication token. Please see the same below,

https://youtu.be/0HwO14p9cjk

Always remember to deploy API after any change :)

Comment: Did it help to sort out the issue?